# Drupal Auction module - Mails not send

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using the Auction module now. The Auction works fine, but there are no emails sent to users when they place a bid. When you insert your bid

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

When I create an account, then i get a email with instructions. Only by the Auction module the mails will not sent. I saw one topic:

[Drupal node 1945662](https://drupal.org/node/1945662)

But there was no good answer for me. I used this module [auction](https://drupal.org/project/auction)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Debugging your Email](https://drupal.org/node/201981) on a development server? Have you looked at the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and the Auction Rules to see if their firing (it sounds like they are)? Did you create [hook_mail_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to see what email drupal thinks it's sending?

Does your "Create Account" email message fully validate as an email sent from a valid domain, etc.

It's email -- there are no easy answers :)

Comment: I get an email when I validate my account, or reset my password. The rules are set and they working. But the email can't be send.